# Where can I find the installed header files for DL4J - INDArray related operations?

Tags: java, maven, deeplearning4j, dl4j, nd4j

I have installed `DL4J` using maven.

I need to see the installed `.so` and `CPP` header files that are used for `INDArray` calls?

*If I am not wrong the EXPORT functions are in NativeOps.h file.*

Where can I find them? I think they are located inside `.m2/repository` in my Ubuntu machine.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

ND4J does not install any header files.

The dynamic library `.so` files (or `.dll` on Windows) are inside their respective `.jar` files (e.g. `nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta7-linux-x86_64.jar`).

You will also find them unpacked in `~/.javacpp/cache/nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta7-linux-x86_64.jar/` where they are put when JavaCPP unpacks and loads them from during execution.

Comment: Actually I need use INDArray pointers into my project where I can fetch them from DL4J (frontend) and pass them to my CPP backend. Here I want to perform operations on them using this pointer (reshape, free etc).  Can there be any work around ?

Comment: As you've also opened an issue about it on github (https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues/9009) lets keep the discussion there.

Comment: Hi Paul, requesting you to answer the above query here or at (github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues/9009). Your help is valuable.